# MySQL generate Sleep queries for WebDAV requests

Tags: mysql, apache, webdav

I need to use Nextcloud WebDAV client api in node.js project. Nextcloud has MySQL DataBase.
For request like this:

```
https://mynextcloud.com/remote.php/webdav/path/to/folder/
```

MySQL generate "Sleep" queries from node project. And this queries sleep about 30 seconds.

[image: MySQL queries]

I don't use any webdav npm packages (just request and xml-js). I also tried to send request by Postman but db queries was "sleep" too. Nextcloud UI get responses fast. Where is the problem?

Comment: What's the problem? "Sleep" is a common thread state for "I'm not doing anything right now."  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-thread-states.html "The thread is waiting for the client to send a new statement to it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a sleep query, that means that the connection is established but not actively performing any queries. The time listed is just how long it's been idle.

Comment: And is it possible to make it not idle when sending webdav request? Sorry for question, this is my first day with mysql

Comment: Normally applications have one or more connections to any associated database(s) and unless they're in the middle of processing something some of these will necessarily be idle. It's generally expensive to create a new connection, the authentication process can take up to a second to complete, so connections are maintained as long as possible. Unless you're running out of connections on your server, idle connections have no real resource costs.

Comment: I understand it, but in my case I can't get any response by webdav in 30 seconds. I send request, then I see new query with command Sleep in db
then I have 30 seconds idle and after that I get response

Comment: Sleep isn't a command. Sleep is a lack of commands. If you're having delays and there's no queries running the problem is not with MySQL but some other part of the system. MySQL would be the problem if you could observe slow, long-running queries that were holding things up. Don't confuse MySQL's sleep state with the `sleep(time)` type function in some programming languages.

Comment: I've gotten ```too many connections``` in my mariadb from nextcloud and had to increase the connection limit.